# Makefile: Kernel module in subfolders

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a more or less complicated LKM. This LKM contains the directories as shown below:

```
├── core.c
├── headers
│   ├── core.h
│   └── server.h
├── include
│   ├── headers
│   │   └── utils.h
│   └── utils.c
├── libs
│   ├── headers
│   │   └── syscalltable.h
│   └── syscalltable.c
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── server.c
├── src
│   ├── getdents_hook.c
│   ├── headers
│   │   ├── getdents_hook.h
│   │   ├── module_hiding.h
│   │   ├── network_keylog.h
│   │   ├── packet_hiding.h
│   │   ├── port_knocking.h
│   │   ├── privilege_escalation.h
│   │   └── socket_hiding.h
│   ├── module_hiding.c
│   ├── network_keylog.c
│   ├── packet_hiding.c
│   ├── port_knocking.c
│   ├── privilege_escalation.c
│   └── socket_hiding.c
└── TASKS.md
```

It seems like a overhead for this small project, but the goal was to create a LKM that could be extended easily.

The problem lies in the Makefile. As every header file is in its respective `headers` subdirectory, I created a Makefile that looks like this:

```
# Module name
ROOTKIT      = rootkit

# Build
CC          = gcc
PWD         = $(shell pwd)
UNAME       = $(shell uname -r)
MODULEDIR   = /lib/modules/$(UNAME)
BUILDDIR    = $(MODULEDIR)/build
KERNELDIR   = $(MODULEDIR)/kernel

# Headers
CORE_H      = headers
LIBS_H      = libs/headers
SRCS_H      = src/headers
INCL_H      = include/headers

# Files
CORE        = $(wildcard *.c)
CORE_OBJS   = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(CORE))
LIBS        = $(wildcard libs/*.c)
LIBS_OBJS   = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(LIBS))
INCL        = $(wildcard include/*.c)
INCL_OBJS   = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(INCL))

# Exception for this one file
NETW        = src/network_keylog.c
NETW_OBJS   = src/network_keylog.o

SRC         = $(wildcard src/*.c)
SRCS        = $(filter-out $(NETW), $(SRC))
SRCS_OBJS   = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

# Objects
# $(CORE_OBJS): $(CORE)
#   $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I$(CORE_H) -I$(INCL_H)

# $(LIBS_OBJS): $(LIBS)
#   $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(INCL_H)

# $(SRCS_OBJS): $(SRCS)
#   $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(INCL_H)

# $(NETW_OBJS): $(NETW)
#   $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I$(SRCS_H) -I$(CORE_H) -I$(INCL_H)

# Module
obj-m       += $(ROOTKIT).o
$(ROOTKIT)-y = $(CORE_OBJS) $(LIBS_OBJS) $(SRCS_OBJS) $(NETW_OBJS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -I$(CORE_H) -I$(INCL_H) -I$(LIBS_H) -I$(SRCS_H)

# Recipes
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

load:
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv4.ko
    insmod $(KERNELDIR)/net/ipv6/netfilter/nf_reject_ipv6.ko
    insmod rootkit.ko

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

However I only get this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build M=/home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64“ wird betreten
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[...]
```

I know that the Makefile executes its procedure in a shell, but I can't understand what command the shell can't execute or why this is failing in general. Or is this approach completely wrong?

**EDIT**: Seems like I missed a missing $ in a -I flag...
However, it still does not compile. The problem is that *every* file includes the `utils.h` in `include/headers/`, and I don't know how to specify the compile procedure so that it works.

Currently:

- all source files include my own header files (meaning in the *.c files are only includes like "xyz.h" and in the headers only <....h >)
- the core.c and server.c include all other header files.
- every source file includes the utils.h header and its "own" header file, except for network_keylog.c: this one also includes server.h.

Current output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64/build M=/home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-amd64“ wird betreten
  CC [M]  /home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit/src/network_keylog.o
/home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit/src/network_keylog.c:1:19: fatal error: utils.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
 #include "utils.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-3-common/scripts/Makefile.build:298: die Regel für Ziel „/home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit/src/network_keylog.o“ scheiterte
make[4]: *** [/home/croemheld/Repositories/lkm-rootkit/src/network_keylog.o] Fehler 1
```

Comment: `-I(CORE_H)` - Did you mean `-I$(CORE_H)`?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, I noticed iit while you were commenting, please see my EDIT note above.

Comment: It's hard to see how making a project difficult to build in the first place contributes to it being easy to extend.  This layout is a mess, and I think its complexity causing more trouble for you than it will ever save down the road.

Comment: @JohnBollinger do you have a suggestion for a better layout? I know the layout is a project specific topic, but maybe you know a better one.

Comment: With that said, it's not clear what the nature of your (new) problem is.  Maybe you don't know that you can pass as many `-I` options as you need?  Or maybe you don't know how to refer to the needed include directory in the first place?

Comment: A better layout: put all C source and header files in `src/` (flat). I don't see what you think your present layout gains you relative to that.